# Dropdown menu , displaying two columns but only when clicked

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a drop down menu populated from a mysql database , is it possible to display two columns from the database but only when clicked ?

By this I mean, when you click you see a list of items on the left and a brief description on the right. The description column should only be visible when clicking on the dropdown.

Is this possible ?

My code is as follow, this queries the DB to check the current selection for the user.
I have tried adding a second column but it shows at all times which looks terrible.

```
            <?php 
require_once('db_connect.php');



$id = $_GET['id'];

$qry = "SELECT issue FROM issuetbl WHERE issueid =?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$client_result = $result->fetch_assoc();

$qry2 = "SELECT data FROM issdd";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry2);
$stmt->execute();
$resultdata = $stmt->get_result();

echo '<select name="enqiss">';  
while($row = $resultdata->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($client_result['issue']==$row['data']){
    $selectCurrent='selected';
}else{
    $selectCurrent='';
}
echo '<option value="'.$row['data'].'" '.$selectCurrent.'>'.$row['data'].'</option>';
 } 
 echo '</select>';



?>
```

Many thanks

Comment: This is possible by using java script and may be json object.

Comment: Would anyone have an example of this ?